# Read from source.sql write to destiantion.sql with python script?

Tags: python

I Have a file source.sql

```
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (1, 0, 'MMB', '2 MB INTERNATIONAL', NULL, NULL, 0)
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (2, 12, '3D STRUCTURES', '3D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 0)
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (2, 0, '2 STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 0)
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (2, 111, '2D STRUCTURES', '3D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 1)
```

I am going to write a new file called destination.sql.It will contains:
The new file will ignore

```
`INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (1, dont wirte if !=0, 'MMB', '2 MB INTERNATIONAL', NULL, NULL, don't write if !=0)
```

My sql may loger than this.but positon is keep in general.
In this case the first number 0 at position[1]
and the second 0 at the position[6] (start count from 0)

That the results should be like this .

```
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (1, 0, 'MMB', '2 MB INTERNATIONAL', NULL, NULL, 0)
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (2, 0, '2 STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 0)
```

Anybody Here Could help me to find the way to format the source.sql file and write new file.
destination.sql

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My sql may loger than this.but positon is keep in general. In this case the first number 0 at position[1] and the second 0 at the position[6] (start count from 0)

to S.Mark, fviktor
I have tried like this

import re

```
RX = re.compile(r'^.*?\(\d+,\s0,.*\s0\)\s*$')

outfile = open('destination.sql', 'w')
for ln in open('source.sql', 'r').xreadlines():
    replace1 = ln.replace("INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (", "")
    replace2 = replace1.replace(")", "")
    list_replace = replace2.split(',')
    #print list_replace
    #print '%s ,%s' % (list_replace[1], list_replace[6])
    if list_replace[6]==0 and list_replace[1] == 0:
        #start write line to destination.sql!!!!!!!! NEED HELP
        #if RX.match(ln):
        outfile.write(ln)
```

(2, x1, '2D STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, x6, 15, 2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2D STRUCTURES', 'MAILLOT 12/08/05', -1, 'tata 20/05/02', 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)

Of cause I don't need to write to destination.sql if the position[1] != 0 and position[6] != 0 in this case are x1 and x6. thanks for your

Comment: There is not reliable way to filter on those fields using regular expressions or any text parsing except of fully parsing the SQL statement. I can come up with a regexp for you, but that might not be reliable. Better solution would be to load the data into MySQL (I guess you use that) by executing those INSERT statements on an empty SQL table having those fields, then delete the records you don't need in your output, then dump that table the get your INSERT statements as text. It would be a much more reliable and generic solution than trying to filter the textual dump.

Comment: But if you have no choice and have to filter the text dump anyway, then here is an (unreliable) regexp for the above: `^INSERT\sINTO.*?\((?:(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL))(?:,\s(\w.*?|'.*?'|NULL)),.*\)\s*$`  This regexp will match on such INSERT statements and extract you the first seven values as match groups. Please note, that unusual values (not a string or a string with an escaped apostrophe in it, NULL is also accepted) before the 7th value might cause problems. You're warned!

Answer (score 1):

You can read line by line and check if it is ends with 0) and match with regex for the other one.

```
import re
dest=open("destination.sql","w+")
for line in open("source.sql","r"):
    if line.strip().endswith("0)") and re.search("\(\d+, 0,",line):
        dest.write(line)
```

Comment: Infact 0 it's always end of line.
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (1, 0, 'MMB', '2 MB INTERNATIONAL', NULL, NULL, 0,0)
It will problem for.
I prefered it's  the position.
in this case 0 at postion[1] (count from 0)
the seconde o at postion [6]

Comment: In fact I have along line more than this.
but the case is postion of line 
in first 0 this case at postion[1] (count from 0) 
the seconde 0 at postion [6]
Sorry for my unsure question.

Comment: for example:
INSERT INTO `Tbl_ABC` VALUES (2, 0, '2D STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 0, 15, 2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2D STRUCTURES', 'MAILLOT 12/08/05', -1, 'tata 20/05/02', 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import re

RX = re.compile(r'^.*?\(\d+,\s0,.*\s0\)\s*$')

outfile = open('destination.sql', 'w')
for ln in open('source.sql', 'r').xreadlines():
    if RX.match(ln):
        outfile.write(ln)
```

Comment: it's quite what I need .I my case if script source like this:
for example: INSERT INTO Tbl_ABC VALUES (2, 0, '2D STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, 0, 15, 2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2D STRUCTURES', 'MAILLOT 12/08/05', -1, 'tata 20/05/02', 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
How I modified this to mach?
RX = re.compile(r'^.*?\(\d+,\s0,.*\s0\)\s*$')

Comment: Which zeros your need to check in these new INSERT statements?

Comment: BTW: That `.xreadlines()` is not really needed since Python 2.3. It does the same as simply iterating on the file. I'm an old timer Python developer, it seems. ;-)

Comment: (2, x1, '2D STRUCTURES', '2D STRUCTURES', NULL, NULL, x6, 15, 2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2D STRUCTURES', 'MAILLOT 12/08/05', -1, 'tata 20/05/02', 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)
of cause I don't need to write to destination.sql if the position[1] != 0 and position[6] != 0 in this case are x1 and x6.
thanks for your helping.